# SwiftUI - Backward gesture recognizer issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I completely hide the navigation bar and the back button in SwiftUI. But I couldn't come back by sliding from the edge of the screen after navigating after hiding it. As you can see in the code I shared below, I can solve this problem when I use this extension. But after pasting this extension under a single view, it affects the whole project and other views. I don't want this. Because when the user provides a member login to the application, it is directed to the main screen with a naavigation. Because of this extension, the user comes back to the login screen when he slides his finger from left to right from the home screen. I don't want this to happen. How can I solve this problem.

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disallow only back to the first (LogIn) screen, then it can be solved just by extending condition

```
public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return viewControllers.count > 1 
       && topViewController !== viewControllers[1]      // << here !!
}
```

Comment: How am I going to use this? I have a view called Homeview (). I just want to disable it in this view.

Comment: In the same way as you used `UINavigationController` before. This is just improved variant for described case.